# Hessian of log-sum-exp $f(z) = \operatorname{log} \sum_{i=1}^n z_i$, find $\nabla^2f(z)$

Tags: derivatives, logarithms, partial-derivative, hessian-matrix

Let $f(z) = \operatorname{log} \sum_{i=1}^n z_i = \operatorname{log} 1^Tz$.

This problem comes from the following famous theorem:

[image]

---

My work:
The following step is just consider one entry of the Hessian matrix:

$$\nabla^2 f(z)_{ij} = \frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial z_i\partial z_j}  = \frac{\partial}{\partial z_i}(\frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial z_j}) = \frac{\partial}{\partial z_i}(\frac{1}{1^Tz})=-\frac{1}{(1^Tz)^2}$$
I have no idea how to obtain the desired form. How to obtain the other term such as $\operatorname{diag(z)}$. Moreover, the numerator here is $1$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that you have to take the derivative with respect to $x$ if you want to check convexity in $x$. This gives some more terms form the chain rule: We have 
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} f(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial z_j} \log 1^tz \cdot \frac{\partial z_j}{\partial x_j} = \frac 1{1^tz} z_j $$
Hence,
\begin{align*} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} 
  &= \frac{\partial}{\partial z_i} \left(\frac{z_j}{1^tz}\right) \cdot \frac{\partial z_i}{\partial x_i}\\
  &=\frac{\delta_{ij}1^tz - z_j}{(1^t z)^2} \cdot \exp x_i\\
  &= \frac{\delta_{ij}z_i\cdot 1^tz - z_iz_j}{(1^t z)^2}\\
  &= \frac{\delta_{ij}z_i}{1^tz} - \frac{z_iz_j}{(1^tz)^2}\\
  &= \left(\frac 1{1^tz} \mathop{\rm diag}(z) - \frac{1}{(1^tz)^2} zz^t\right)_{i,j}
 \end{align*}

Comment: Can you explain a bit about $\delta_{ij}$?

Comment: The so called Kronecker symbol, a shorthand for $\delta_{ij} = 1$ iff $i=j$, otherwise $\delta_{ij} = 0$.