# Finding Lipschitz constant from Gradient and Hessian of log-sum-exp

Tags: inequality, continuity, convex-analysis, lipschitz-functions, hessian-matrix

I have calculated the Gradient and Hessian of log-sum-exp as mentioned in the accepted answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2089941/hessian-of-log-sum-exp-fz-operatornamelog-sum-i-1n-z-i-find-nabl). I would like to find Lipschitz constant L, in $|F(x)-F(x^{'})| \leq L ||x-x'||_2$. I have been at this problem for 2 days but unable to find a solution. What am I missing?

Comment: You need an estimate for the largest eigenvalue of the Hessian. I think that the second (negative) term can be neglected.

Comment: But how do we find eigenvalues of the first term? Also, I found out that, to get the Lipschitz constant of the above inequality, one can use the Gradient of the function. Is this true? If so, how?