# Convexity of difference of log-sum-exp: $f(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = \log(e^{x_1} + e^{x_2}) - \log(e^{x_1} + e^{x_2} + e^{x_3} + e^{x_4})$

Tags: logarithms, convex-analysis

I would like to know whether the following function $f: \mathbf{R}^4 \to \mathbf{R}$ is concave or not:

$$
f(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = \log(e^{x_1} + e^{x_2}) - \log(e^{x_1} + e^{x_2} + e^{x_3} + e^{x_4})
$$

I tried to check whether the Hessian was negative semi-definite, but did not get anywhere. The Hessian can be written as

$$
\nabla^2 f(x) = 
\frac{1}{\tilde{Z}^2}(\tilde{Z} \cdot \text{diag}(\tilde{\mathbf{z}}) - \tilde{\mathbf{z}}\tilde{\mathbf{z}}^\intercal)
-
\frac{1}{Z^2}(Z \cdot \text{diag}(\mathbf{z}) - \mathbf{z} \mathbf{z}^\intercal),
$$

where
$$
\tilde{\mathbf{z}} = \begin{bmatrix} e^{x_1} & e^{x_2} & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^\intercal \\
\mathbf{z} = \begin{bmatrix} e^{x_1} & e^{x_2} & e^{x_3} & e^{x_4} \end{bmatrix}^\intercal \\
\tilde{Z} = e^{x_1} + e^{x_2} \\
Z = e^{x_1} + e^{x_2} + e^{x_3} + e^{x_4}
$$
but I did not get much further than that. **Any help would be greatly appreciated!**

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1189638) discusses in detail the convexity of the log-sum-exp function, but does not apply to my case (difference of fcts).

Comment: Fixing $x_2=x_3=x_4=0$, we get the function $\log(e^x+1)-\log(e^x+3)$. Take the second derivative, simplify, see that it changes sign.

Comment: @Bookend, thanks, that's simple & clear! Would you like to write a proper answer for it? I'd be glad to accept it.

Comment: @Bookend, I asked a question on meta about this: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23554 - would love to get more explanations from you why you think this is a bad question.

Comment: @Bookend This question is of perfect use to others. I, for one, found it very informative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(This answer builds up on the first comment to the question above).

Short answer: **no**, the function is not concave.

Instead of analyzing the full $4 \times 4$ hessian, we can start by restricting our attention to a subspace of the input, e.g., the line induced by setting $x_2 = x_3 = x_4 = 0$. Along this line, the original function can be rewritten as a univariate function $\tilde{f}(x) = \log(e^x + 1) - \log(e^x + 3)$.

the second derivative of $\tilde{f}$ is
$$
\frac{d^2\tilde{f}}{dx^2} = \frac{e^x(6 - 2 e^{2x})}{(e^x + 1)^2 (e^x + 3)^2}
$$
it is easy to see that the second derivative is positive for $x = 0$, hence $\tilde{f}$ is not concave (furthemore, it is negative for $x =  1$, so it is not convex either).
We conclude that $f$ is not concave.

Note that the type of functions described here (difference of log-sum-exps) appears in the log-likelihood function of certain statistical models of paired comparisons, such as [Elimination by Aspects](https://homepage.uni-tuebingen.de/florian.wickelmaier/pubs/WickelmaierSchmid2004BRMIC.pdf) and [team comparisons](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume7/huang06a/huang06a.pdf).